# UITableViewCellStyle Custom iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm having a bit confusion with the UITableViewCellStyle. I want to create a custom UITableViewCell like this:

[image]

But the text and the image not appear in the cell when I run the app. In Storyboard,I've put the TableView Style to 'Custom'.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**MainTableViewController**

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "CustomMainCell.h"

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCell";

@interface MainTableViewController ()

//
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataSource;

//
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *iconsSource;

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Currículum Vitae";

    // Inicializo los arrays con los datos
    self.dataSource = @[@"PERFIL",@"EXPERIENCIA",@"EDUCACIÓN",@"HABILIDADES",@"INTERESES"];
    self.iconsSource = @[@"perfil.png",@"experiencia.png",@"educacion.png",@"habilidades.png",@"intereses"];

    // Register Class for Cell Reuse Identifier
    [self.tableView registerClass:[CustomMainCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // This will remove extra separators from tableview
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // Eliminio las líneas que separan las celdas
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.dataSource.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomMainCell *cell = (CustomMainCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomMainCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.title.text = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
    cell.icon.image = self.iconsSource[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**CustomMainCell.h**

```
@interface CustomMainCell : UITableViewCell

//
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;

//
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *icon;

@end
```

**CustomMainCell.m**

```
#import "CustomMainCell.h"

@implementation CustomMainCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have:

```
// Register Class for Cell Reuse Identifier
[self.tableView registerClass:[CustomMainCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

because the cell is registered from the storyboard when the view controller is unarchived. By registering the class you are removing the archive (NIB) registration.

Additionally:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomMainCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

shouldn't be required as you will always get a valid cell back (because the identifier is registered)

Comment: Ok, it works, but if I remove those lines of code, the 
 method - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier method in CustomMainCell.h won't be executed. Which is the best place to modify the Cell appearence? In the MainTableViewController or in the CustomMainCell?

Comment: In the storyboard... The init with coder method and awake from nib methods will be called.